# D8 to D8 migrate source plugin?

Tags: 8, migrations

[Migrate Source](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source)

> The migration configuration entity always contains a source key. The
>   value is an associative array containing the name of the plugin and
>   the configuration of it. Only the plugin key-value pair is mandatory,
>   some plugins might not have any configurations.
>
> ```
> source:
>   plugin: d6_node
> ```

Googling I see examples outhere that use `d6_node` and `d7_node` but what does one use to migrate nodes from d8 to d8?

Looking at the `core/modules/node/src/Plugin/migrate/source` folder there is no such thing as `d8_node`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Drupal 8 migration module has been moved into core as explained in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2935951). If you're using at least Drupal 8.6.x, you don't need to apply the patch.

---

Old answer:

I'm going out on a limb and say that currently there isn't one and it can only be done by creating a custom plugin.

Just found this [Drupal 8 migration (source)](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_drupal_d8), thanks [Berdir](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/31/berdir) & [Primsi](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/7616/primsi).

Comment: Primsi did most of the work, thank him :) I just created the project and did some reviews.